# Put option price where premium is paid at exercise

Tags: black-scholes

Let's say there is a put option but the premium is paid at exercise.

This means the strike must be seen as the strike + premium.

How would you go about solving this?

Answer (score 1):

For a put option the modified strike would be ‘strike’ - premium.  But, there is no way to solve for the premium, because the whole thing represents a free option to the holder.  (Proof: there is no scenario where the holder loses money).

Comment: putting aside any issues with it being a free option, how would it be solved mathematically?

Comment: As I mentioned, any value of the premium you plug in, gives a positive value to the option, except if you plug in premium = strike.  Then the fair  value is zero.  Mathematically that is the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your modelling of "strike - premium" is correct.

If I bought a "normal" put option with a strike of 10 for 2, and the underlying was at 9 at expiry, I would have lost 1 (made 1 on the option but paid 2 upfront). That's a different payoff than adjusting the option to have a strike of 8.

The only difference between this option and a "standard" option is that the premium deferred until exercise ($P_E$) would just be the future value (at some interest rate) of the present normal premium ($P_0$):

$$
P_E = P_0 \times e^{rt_E}
$$

Where $r$ and $t_E$ are the interest rate and time from initiation to exercise, respectively.

The payoff at expiry would then be:

$$
   \max(0, K-S) - P_0 \times e^{rt_E}
$$

If this were a European option, and could only be exercised at expiry, you could apply that to the black-scholes formula for a put option (setting $t_E = T$), and would get:

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
P_E &=& (KN(−d2)e^{−rT} − S(0)N(−d1)) \times e^{rT}\\
&=& KN(−d2) − S(0)N(−d1)e^{rT}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$

Note that it's possible for a *different* interest rate to be used to calculate the premium future value than the present value of the option, since the rate used in the option value is a "risk-free" rate, while the option holder is essentially "loaning" you the premium, and may charge a different interest rate for such a benefit.

Comment: That is not my interpretation of the contract.  I’m assuming that the OP means that in your example, if the stock was at 9, the option would not be exercised.

Comment: The OP says ‘premium on exercise’, rather than ‘premium on expiration’.   If it were the latter, I agree with your analysis.

Comment: Good catch - in that case, the principle would be the same - you'd just take the future value of the premium from initiation to exercise instead of expiry, and the application to black-scholes would not necessarily apply.  In either case, modelling as an option with an adjusted strike would not be correct.